# Socket Programming - iPhone - connection getting disconnected automatically

Tags: iphone, sockets, chat

I am trying to implement a chat client in iPhone APP. I'm using the below code to open the socket connection. But my stream connection is automatically getting disconnected frequently. What will be the issue? How can I maintain the connection until it is closed manually through the code?

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication {

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"111.122.123.124", (UInt32)123, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream =  (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *) readStream;
outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];

[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];

}
```

Comment: There are usually timeouts for read and write that you can configure. Maybe the timeout intervals are to short...

Comment: where i should give the time interval?

Comment: I really don't know I never used this classes, but I was using GCDAsyncSocket for tcp connections and had the similar problem, so my comment was just a direction pointer. Connections usually break after some idle (read/write) period...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198427/srwebsocket-connection-is-closing-automatically-after-keeping-app-idle-for-somet

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a websocket - not sending any data it will automatically disconnect from a server side usually.

Standard configuration is around 1 minute for that - until 60 second of idle time it will disconnect a client from a server by sending valid end connection info.

Check configuration for your server to higher value or send a heartbeat packet each 30 seconds to keep connection alive.

Comment: I'm using the websocket